# Gatsby error: You can only call end() on a span once. How to fix this?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, graphql, cloud, gatsby

I am running Gatsby + WP and have not seen this error until updating my gatsby-source-wordpress plugin.

The error message does not give me any information about where this is occuring so I am compeltely stuck.

I tried simply clearing my cache but that didn't do anything.

I am not getting errors in my local environment, but I when I push this to Gatsby cloud the build fails and gives me the message.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if my answer will be helpful to you. But I had the same error when I pushed my code which worked fine in my local environment.

After spending some time debugging, I realised that the problem that stopped building wasn't related to the error message at all.

After I fixed the bug I still got the same error but the build succeed. So I recommend you try to check another factor that might cause the build to fail.